# Magento 2.3.x - Subscribe to newsletter checkbox at onepage checkpout page - error during subscription

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, newsletter-subscriber

My requirement was to add a "subscribe to newsletter" checkbox at onepage checkout page (below "terms and condition" checkbox). All the things are fine except 2 issues:

1. The user MUST NOT be subscribed if he unchecks the checkboxes.
2. **For the very first time when the user mail is not there in DB for newletter subscription and I hit the place order button, the page is broken** but if the email is already there in DB (under newsletter subscribers in admin) and the user places the order and dont uncheck the chekbox, all fine.

I played with the observer **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** (code below):

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Register to Newsletter during checkout process
 */

namespace <Mynamespace>\<Mymodule>\Observer\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class OrderPlaceBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_subscriber;
    protected $_request;
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @param Subscriber $subscrbr
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Subscriber $subscrbr,
        RequestInterface $request,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_subscriber = $subscrbr;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }


    /**
     * Subscribe to newsletters if customer checked the checkbox
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerEmail = $order->getCustomerEmail();

        try {
            **//Here the conditions should go, if the checkbox is checked then only subscribe to newsletter otherwise not
            //How to get custom checkbox value after order placement? Tried with $this->_request->getpost() but not working, returning an empty array**
            $subscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

            if (!$subscriber->getId()) {
                //at this line, first time for non-existing email, the page is broken, not sure WHY??
                $this->_subscriber->subscribe($customerEmail);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage() . ' from Mynamespace-Mymodule ' . $customerEmail);
        }


        return $this;
    }
}
```

Not sure where I am wrong? Can you please guide?
Thanks in advance.